# Oracle VM: After install, black screen after Ubuntu 16.10 splash screen

Tags: boot, virtualbox, 16.10

Ubuntu seemed to install correctly. When the VM starts some seemingly benign text appears on the screen and then goes to the splash screen. After the splash screen it goes to a completely black screen. I'm using the latest ubuntu and oracle vm. My vm is set to linux 32bit.

What I've tried:
Reinstalling Ubuntu,
Adjusting screen resolution, 
Hard/Soft reset (underscore appears and shutdown during soft reset)

Ubuntu version: ubuntu-16.10-desktop-i386
Oracle VM: 5.1.10